# Why my Android device is applying sw410dp styles when it is 480dp?

Tags: android, emulation, dimensions

I am testing an Android app in different screen sizes. For that, I have created dimensions for 360dp, 390dp, 410dp and 480dp (also have a default values.xml).

I was testing and adjusting styles on emulators and everything was OK. However, when I tested this on a Motorola g22 physical device, the styles are broken.

I have researched in Google and it has a 720px x 1600px, 6.5 inches. It is a hdpi (1.5 dpi).
So, applying the equation I found in [this blog](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-density-independent-pixel-sp-dp-dip-in-android/)

```
px = dp * dpi / 160 = dp * hdpi

dp = px / hdpi

dp = 720 / 1.5

dp = 480dp
```

To be sure, I manually created an emulator hardware profile with that same resolution and it effectively has 480dp.
[image]

Due to a couple of tests, I discovered it is applying the dimensions from the 410dp but couldn't find the reason why.

On the other hand, the 480dp emulator I have been using for testing is Galaxy A12. It has the same characteristics but, in this case, the 480dp dimens are applied correcly.

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: "I have created dimensions for 360dp, 390dp, 410dp and 480dp" -- that is a significant code smell. There are tens of thousands of Android device models, with hundreds of distinct screen resolutions.

Comment: Ok, so what do you recommend to cover different resolutions?

Comment: If your designers are creating completely independent designs for each one of those sizes, your designers are drunk, and dimension resources will not help you. Otherwise, you work with your designers to determine what the rules are for adapting their design to different screen dimensions, and implement the layout/composables to match those rules. It is rather unlikely that requires hundreds of separate dimension resource value files, or even five of them. If you run into problems in determining how to implement their rules, ask additional Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: I have no designers, it is a personal project. However, you are telling me I am doing a very bad practice. Ok, but you are not saying why nor giving another option. I've applied the swXdp approach because that's what I've read as good practice to be responsive for the different device resolutions.
Also, supposing I am using a bad approach, you are not answering why it is taking the 410dp instead of 480dp.
You may be right what you are not saying, but you are not helping me in any way with those comments.

Comment: "but you are not saying why nor giving another option" -- the details will vary based on the design you are trying to implement. "I've applied the swXdp approach because that's what I've read as good practice to be responsive for the different device resolutions" -- for major changes and completely different designs for different screen sizes, such as between a phone and a tablet, using `swNNNdp` layout resources used to be a great approach. Using them for dimensions was never a great approach, let alone using them for fine-grained size differences.

Comment: "you are not answering why it is taking the 410dp instead of 480dp" -- there is not enough information in your question to answer that. It would take a complete project (e.g., in GitHub) for somebody to answer that, most likely.

Comment: @CommonsWare just another person commenting only to remark someone is doing something "wrong". Double quotes because you are just saying, not giving any helpful information :)